# Displaying fetched profile picture in Navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Hope you can notice a prof pic in this below Image[image] but the random guy who did it just hard coded the Image. I have fetched the username, E-mail ID and prof pic from Facebook and I have hooked username and E-mail id with navigation drawer activity,but I don't know how to display the prof_pic which I fetched from Facebook I just don't no how to assign it. let me know if there is any possible way to do it.the below is the nav_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profpic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the java file where I need to fetch the prof_pic from
.java class file

```
public class Testing2 extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ////////Code is used to fetch the user name////////////
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        TextView facebookName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.manner);
        TextView Email = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.email);
        ImageView profilePictureView = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profpic);

        ////////Code is used to display the user name after fetching it from other activity////////////
        facebookName.setText(b.getCharSequence("name"));
        Email.setText(b.getCharSequence("email"));
        profilePictureView.setProfileId();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

  }
```

This is the .java file where I used to fetch the username,mail Id and prof pic

```
public class SelfTrail extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LoginButton btnLogin;
    TextView facebookName;
    TextView Email;
    Button button;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_self_trail);
        findAllViewsId();
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnLogin = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        facebookName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.image);


        btnLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            facebookName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profilePictureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        btnLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("Main", response.toString());
                                setProfileToView(object);
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

            }
        });
       }




    private void findAllViewsId() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        facebookName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Testing2.class);
        //Create a bundle object
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
        b.putString("name", facebookName.getText().toString());
        b.putString("email", Email.getText().toString());
        b.putString("image", profilePictureView.toString());

        //Add the bundle to the intent.
        intent.putExtras(b);

        //start the DisplayActivity
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        facebookName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        Email.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.NORMAL);
                        profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }


    private void setProfileToView(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            facebookName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            Email.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));

            profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.NORMAL);
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be using Picasso Library. It automatically fetches image from url in background and sets it to the imageView.

Add this to the build.gradle file under dependencies

```
          compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And then in your code instead of profilePictureView.setProfileId(); use

```
          Picasso.with(this).load( "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small").into(profilePictureView)
```

Where userID is the used id of the profile.

Comment: If you want me to exactly copy the code you have given.I did it and the error is 'error: illegal start of expression' and should I replace something in the place of '<the url of image you get from facebook>'

Comment: Yes . replace it with the url of image you got from facebook.

Comment: when I tried and applied the saved value  like this 'Picasso.with(this).load(<profilePictureView>).into(profilePictureView);' I ma hitting the same error

Comment: no no profilePictureView is your imageView. You have somthing like b.getCharSequence("name") for name right. Same way you wouldve added something of that sort to profile image right. Add that inside the braces and remove < & >

Comment: Ramesh I just edited the code and added the .java part which i used to get the userName,email id and prof pic from facebook, can you please take a look at it help me through this

Comment: What is ProfilePictureView

Comment: I used to save the fetched image the image from Facebook

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can get the user id from id tag in facebook.Try this out.

Comment: The error I am facing now is cannot resolve userid.I dont no where to fetch the userid

Comment: userId= profilePictureView.getProfileId(). If you dont have a method called getProfileId(); You are setting it using  profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id")). Fetch that profile id here.

Comment: I just edited the code ' Picasso.with(this).load( "http://graph.facebook.com/"+ profilePictureView +"/picture?type=small").into(profilePictureView);' like this but  still image was not fetched.

Comment: it should be Picasso.with(this).load( "graph.facebook.com/"+ profilePictureView.getId() +"/picture?type=small").into(profilePictureView)

Comment: I used the exact code u gave still didn't workout I don't no what to do now

Comment: I have assigned ProfilePictureView  to profilePictureView and the class is used in all other steps,

Comment: You are using profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id")) right. In this jsonObject.getString("id") is the user id. Just add it to your bundle or something and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this does:

`profilePictureView.setProfileId();`

But to set the image just use:

`profilePictureView.setImageBitmap(pass_image_bitmap_here);`

Comment: Just like @RageshRamesh said, you should use Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

You can always you image loading library for loading images in efficient way (Like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)). 
In you case, (using Picasso) you can write

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img)
       .error(R.drawable.error_img)
       .into(profilePictureView);
```

Where your url = https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=150

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the user ID for the user, then you can call a function like this:

```
/**
 * Function loads the users facebook profile pic
 * 
 * @param userID
 */
public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {
    String imageURL;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading Picture");
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I came up with.

Use `Picasso` library which is used for image processing in android.

1. Add dependency in gradle:

   `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`
2. Add in your activity to display the fetched image:

   ```
   Picasso.with(context)
      .load(url)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img)
      .error(R.drawable.error_img)
      .into(profilePictureView);
   ```